# PYTHON WSGI info log goes in apache2 error.log

Tags: python, apache, wsgi

I have a WSGI app running on Apache. But I have a little issue pretty annoying. All my logs  goes into the error.log apache2 file, even if it's INFO log.

Here is my Log class, if you have and idea, thanks in advance

```
class Log:
    def __init__(self, path, smtp):
        self.smtp = smtp
        self.filename = ''
        self.LOGGER = logging.getLogger('Open-Capture')
        if self.LOGGER.hasHandlers():
            self.LOGGER.handlers.clear()  # Clear the handlers to avoid double logs
        log_file = RotatingFileHandler(path, mode='a', maxBytes=5 * 1024 * 1024,
                                       backupCount=2, encoding=None, delay=False)
        formatter = logging.Formatter(
            '[%(name)-17s] [%(file)-26sline %(line_n)-3s] %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
            datefmt='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
        log_file.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.LOGGER.addHandler(log_file)

        self.LOGGER.filters.clear()
        self._filter = CallerFilter()
        self.LOGGER.addFilter(self._filter)
        self.LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    @caller_reader
    def info(self, msg):
        self.LOGGER.info(unidecode(msg))
```

And here is my apache2 config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/opencapture_runtime/
    WSGIDaemonProcess opencapture_runtime user=nathan group=nathan threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /runtime /var/www/html/opencapture_runtime/opencapture.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/html/opencapture_runtime/>
        AllowOverride All
        WSGIProcessGroup opencapture_runtime
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIPassAuthorization On
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Example of apache log :

```
[Wed Jul 06 10:25:23.577457 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 37073] [remote ::1:42356] INFO:Open-Capture:Authentification successful. IP Address : ::1
```